# Ubuntu user access rights for Jenkins

Tags: application-development, qt, jenkins

I have Two users on Ubuntu setup
user : kmb and user : dev
where user kmb has installation of Qt, Qt for webassembly and Jenkins server also
where as dev has nothing installed in it

so when i login to dev and i want to build webassembly Qt applications (In dev but setup is in kmb), i am getting some absulute path warnings and make fails to build qt applications refer below for error log

```
WARNING  root: -I or -L of an absolute path "-I/home/devops/.emscripten_ports/openssl/include" encountered. If this is to a local system header/library, it may cause problems (local system files make sense for compiling natively on your system, but not necessarily to JavaScript). Pass '-Wno-warn-absolute-paths' to emcc to hide this warning.
WARNING  root: Disabling asm.js validation for memory growth (memory can grow, but you lose some amount of speed)
/home/kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/bin/rcc -name qml ../qml.qrc -o qrc_qml.cpp
em++ -c -pipe -O3 -std=gnu++11 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -Wall -Wextra -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QMLMODELS_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../Test -I. -I../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/include -I../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/include/QtQuick -I../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/include/QtGui -I../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/include/QtQmlModels -I../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/include/QtQml -I../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/include/QtNetwork -I../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/include/QtCore -I. -I/home/devops/.emscripten_ports/openssl/include -I../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/mkspecs/wasm-emscripten -o qrc_qml.o qrc_qml.cpp
WARNING  root: -I or -L of an absolute path "-I/home/devops/.emscripten_ports/openssl/include" encountered. If this is to a local system header/library, it may cause problems (local system files make sense for compiling natively on your system, but not necessarily to JavaScript). Pass '-Wno-warn-absolute-paths' to emcc to hide this warning.
WARNING  root: Disabling asm.js validation for memory growth (memory can grow, but you lose some amount of speed)
em++ -pipe -O3 -std=gnu++11 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -Wall -Wextra -dM -E -o moc_predefs.h ../../../../kmb/Qt/5.14.0/wasm_32/mkspecs/features/data/dummy.cpp
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1'
Makefile:624: recipe for target 'moc_predefs.h' failed
make: *** [moc_predefs.h] Error 1
```

so what is cause here?